# WPF Popup PlacementMode.Bottom not behaving as expected

Tags: wpf, popup

I have a very simple app with a single handler on a button that shows a popup:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Popup popup =
        new Popup
        {
            Width = 200,
            Height = 20,
            Child = new Rectangle { Fill = Brushes.Fuchsia },
            PlacementTarget = (Button)sender,
            Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom,
            IsOpen = true,
        };
}
```

It yields the following result:

### [image: Actual popup behavior]

By changing the placement mode to PlacementMode.Custom and adding a callback (omitted), I can achieve the following:

### [image: Desired popup behavior]

However, I would expect that this would be the default behavior for PlacementMode.Bottom. From MSDN:

> PlacementMode = Bottom
>
> A position of the Popup control where the control aligns its upper edge with the lower edge of the PlacementTarget and aligns its left edge with the left edge of the PlacementTarget.

### [image: MSDN Image]

Am I misreading the documentation or doing something else wrong? Why doesn't my simple app look / act how the documentation says (at least how I currently read it) it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this running on a PC or a tablet? Apparently the "handedness" setting on tablets changes the behaviour of the alignment of the pop-up. (Maybe also look at if right-to-left languages are a factor?)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/19ef3d33-01e5-45c5-a845-d64f9231001c

Other than this, have you tried using a XAML approach rather than code-behind?

Comment: This is on a PC, but I will try a full XAML approach next.

Comment: I did have a touch monitor installed at one point, and I think that may have something to do with it. After reading the link in your response and related sites, I'm going to use a custom callback to absolutely position my box regardless of handedness.

Comment: Happens when you run your Windows in a VM hosted on OSX, too.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem today - I think you can make use of 2 other properties to adjust where the popup should be placed (HorizontalOffset and VerticalOffset - can take both positive and negative numbers)

Example at http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/resources/699/how-to-position-a-popup-in-wpf.aspx